# Expected ':' in dictionary literal

Tags: swift

This is my first attempt to create a Dictionary:

```
    var powerup: Dictionary = [String: Any]()

    powerup = [
        "dynamite" :
            ["tier0":
                ["effect" : 0]],
            ["tier1" :
                ["effect" : 1]]
        ]
```

I get the error 'Expected ':' in dictionary literal'. What is wrong with my dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like that:

```
var powerup: Dictionary = [String: Any]()

    powerup = [
        "dynamite" :
            [
                "tier0":
                    ["effect" : 0],
                "tier1" :
                    ["effect" : 1]
            ]
    ]
```

Count your brackets

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly normal since you forget something in you dictionary literal. 
I think this will work better :

```
powerup = ["dynamite":
    [
        ["tier0":
            ["effect": 0]
        ],
        ["tier1" :
            ["effect": 1]
        ]
    ]
]
```

This is what you need to do if you want to describe a dictionary containing one key named dynamite linked to an array that contains two dictionary each one containing one key linked to a dictionary containing one key linked to one integer value.

You may want to rethink you data structure to since it's quite complicated.

Comment: You are needlessly adding an extra layer of dictionaries in this answer.